# Set degree of Nodes

Tags: neo4j, oncreate

I have a graph in which I am keeping the degree of a node as a property called "degree" in the node.

What I need is when I create an edge between two nodes, I need to increment the degree of the two nodes.

For creating unique edges I am using "CREATE UNIQUE" for the edges. So if I need to increment the property "degree" of the corresponding nodes, I need to use "ON CREATE" and "ON MATCH" as it is for "MERGE".

But I can't use the ON CREATE and ON MATCH with CREATE UNIQUE. So whats the proper way of using ON CREATE and ON MATCH with CREATE UNIQUE?

This is the way I am trying:

```
MATCH (n1:PER {Node_Id:"X"}), (n2:PER {Node_Id:"Y"}) WHERE n1.Node_Id<>n2.Node_Id CREATE UNIQUE (n1)-[r:PER_PER {Doc_Id:"st_new", Event_Class:"EC_1", Event_Instance:"EI_1"}]-(n2) ON CREATE SET n1.degree = n1.degree + 1, n2.degree = n2.degree + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to store the degree as a property. Neo4j has a `getDegree()` function on API level, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#getDegree(). Cypher is not yet using this everywhere possible but for some patterns it already does.

Nevertheless to answer your question: just use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE UNIQUE` for eventually establishing the relationship:

```
MATCH (n1:PER {Node_Id:"X"}), (n2:PER {Node_Id:"Y"}) 
WHERE n1.Node_Id<>n2.Node_Id 
MERGE (n1)-[r:PER_PER {Doc_Id:"st_new", Event_Class:"EC_1", Event_Instance:"EI_1"}]-(n2)    
ON CREATE SET n1.degree = n1.degree + 1, n2.degree = n2.degree + 1
```

Comment: Thank You Stefan.....Kind of new to neo4j  and so not familiar with the REST API....so I am not considering the use of getDegree().
But definitely I have resorted to use the MERGE instead of CREATE UNIQUE. And It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a good reason to store node degrees as a property, please have a look at one of our modules called [RelCount](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-relcount), which has been build exactly for what you need to do. It is described in detail in my [thesis](http://graphaware.com/assets/bachman-msc-thesis.pdf).

However, as Stefan points out, have a go with `getDegree()` first and only if that isn't fast enough, or you need to get degree based on some relationship property values as well, use RelCount.

Comment: I have tried using MERGE with ON SET and ON CREATE, and that is serving my purpose for now. So I have not tried the getDegree() function.

But the RelCount module will be much better for my purpose I guess. I shall keep it as an advanced option for future.
Thank you so much Michal for sharing your module.